# Retrieving value from NSXMLElement

Tags: ios, iphone, xmpp, nsxmlelement

I'm trying to retrieve "number" from the below mentioned code.

```
<iq from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    id=‘XYZ'
    to='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='urn:XYZ:number'>
    <number xmlns=‘urn:XYZ:number'>4</number>
  </query>
</iq>
```

I tried the following but it always updates as "0" but i can see iq has different number than 0

```
            NSXMLElement *query = [iq childElement];
            NSXMLElement *number = [query elementForName:@“number"];
            NSInteger number = [number attributeIntegerValueForName:@"number
"];
```

Comment: I don't want to make any assumptions, but with the code you have provided, it looks like you are trying to directly access XML nodes from a string of XML. Has that XML already been parsed?

Comment: yes, and i have values in query and number..

Comment: i just need to know, how to retrieve this number "4" in the above code... the above code NSXMLElement *number = [query elementForName:@“number"]; gives me <number xmlns=‘urn:XYZ:number'>4</number> ... i need to know how to take out the number "4" from this element and save it in NSInteger

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962027/parsing-nsxmlnode-attributes-in-cocoa - In the first answer under the question it looks like they loop through the attributes of the element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
NSXMLElement *number = [query elementForName:@"number" xmlns:@"urn:XYZ:number"];
```

Namespaces matter.  This uses the NSXMLElement category added by XMPPFramework.  More details [here](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/blob/master/Categories/NSXMLElement+XMPP.h).

Your XML could also be simplified as such:

```
<iq from='coven@chat.shakespeare.lit'
    id=‘XYZ'
    to='hag66@shakespeare.lit/pda'
    type='result'>
  <query xmlns='urn:XYZ:number'>
    <number>4</number>
  </query>
</iq>
```

The namespace on the `query` element applies to all child elements.